# "has to rush" or "has to be rushed": which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

I don't understand why "rushed" is used in the following sentence:

> Members of Congress had to be rushed to a secure location in a
> basement.

PS: from [TE](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/06/08/americas-probe-into-the-capitol-riot-is-needed-before-its-too-late)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means they were *led in a hurry* to a new location because those idiots that invaded the Capitol were nearby.

to lead in a hurry somewhere is to rush somewhere.
to be rushed is a passive use and means someone is rushing you somewhere.

They were *rushed by* the Capitol police.